# Unable to load the activity with fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-activity

This is my first time run with `Fragments`. Have a look at the below code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/firstViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.example.fragmenttest.FirstView"/>

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/secondViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.example.fragmenttest.SecondView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_view1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewOneText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="92dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:text="First View"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewOneBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Click Here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_view2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffddff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:text="View 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondViewBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondViewText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**FirstView.java**

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstView extends Fragment
{
    private TextView firstText;
    private Button btn;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        firstText = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.viewOneText);
        btn = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.viewOneBtn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new ButtonEvent());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view1,container,false);
        return view;

    }

    private class ButtonEvent implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            firstText.setText("First View Btn Clicked");

        }

    }
}
```

**SecondView.java**

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondView extends Fragment
{
    private TextView secondText;
    private Button secondViewBtn;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        secondText = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.secondViewText);
        secondViewBtn = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.secondViewBtn);

        secondViewBtn.setOnClickListener(new ButtonEvent());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view2,container,false);
        return view;

    }

    private class ButtonEvent implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            secondText.setText("Second View Text changed");

        }

    }
}
```

When I run this application, I get the following error

```
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmenttest/com.example.fragmenttest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.example.fragmenttest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  ... 11 more
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.fragmenttest.FirstView cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
11-26 12:18:36.137: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  ... 21 more
```

Why am I unable to run this?

**UPDATE**

As SO users mentioned, I changed my `MainActivity`

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now I have the following error

```
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmenttest/com.example.fragmenttest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.example.fragmenttest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  ... 11 more
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.example.fragmenttest.FirstView.onCreateView(FirstView.java:19)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
11-26 12:35:34.137: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` must be extend  `FragmentActivity` from the support library..

And in your onCreateView() of first fragment this is the first line

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view1,container,false);
```

and replace `getView()` with `view`

Comment: Hello, I submitted an update. I am still having the error. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

at least, `MainActivity` should extend `FragmentActivity`.

After that in your fragments:

This code:

```
firstText = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.viewOneText);
btn = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.viewOneBtn);

btn.setOnClickListener(new ButtonEvent());
```

should go after you inflate anything:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view1,container,false);
```

Please, return to the fragments docs to understand them deeper. Now it seems you don't have more or less clear vision of how to use fragments. Your questions will persist until you get fragments know better. Good luck and welcome back if you have any issues.

Comment: Hello, I submitted an update. I am still having the error. Please have a look.

Comment: Read carefully your logs: it clearly states you have NullPointerException in FirstView class on line 19.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a mix of Fragment from Android SDK 11 and support Fragments.

There are 2 solutions :

- as @Vladimir Ivanov suggested, you could use a FragmentActivity (which is the support Activity that deals with support Fragments)
- you could use a android.app.Fragment (which is the Android SDK 11+ Fragment that goes well  with support andorid.app.Activity of SDK 11+)

This is really a bit confusing, as some classes share the same name. But you must decide either to use Android SDK 11+ or the support library to support devices from SDK 7+. You can't mix those classes.

Comment: Hello, I submitted an update. I am still having the error. Please have a look.

Comment: The error is now different, you forgot to inflate your xml in the first line of OnCreateView in FirstFragment

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to cast a `SupportMapFragmen`t to be a native API Level 11 android.app.Fragment. That will not work. Either:

Set your `android:minSdkVersion` to 11 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

the question is simple.you should create FragmentManager  and FragmentTransaction is constance to manager fragment

Comment: No, this only applies to dynamic fragments, not those inflated via XML.